# AspectJ aspect for OnItemClickListener.onItemClick

Tags: android, aspectj

I was wondering if you have an idea on how to write an AspectJ advice that executes after the execution of Android's `OnItemClickListener.onItemClick` method.

I tried `after(View view) : execution(void OnItemClickListener+.onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int, long)) && args(view)`, but AspectJ complains about "can't use parameterized type patterns for the declaring type of an execution pointcut expression (use the raw type instead)," specifically about the execution part.

If I change the advice to `execution(void *.onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int, long))`, then the advice is not applied.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Silviu

Comment: Found out the solution: `after(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int a, long b) : execution(void AdapterView.OnItemClickListener+.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)) && args(parent, view, a, b)`

Answer (score -1):

The handling of generics in Aspect4j has been introduced with:

Then, if your project allow it, you can workaround this issue by upgrading to the latest version. With maven, upgrading to

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
</plugin>
```

solved the issue.

Then, I use

```
pointcut OnClickListener_onClick(View v) :
    execution(void OnClickListener.onClick(View)) && args(v);

after(View v) : OnClickListener_onClick(v) {
    ...
}
```